# "Could not load Vox Preferences preference pane." Solutions?

Tags: macos, itunes, system-settings

I'm trying to install the Vox prefs pane so I can have it use the play/pause next and previous media keys rather than iTunes. However after installing, I get the error "Could not load Vox Preferences preference pane". I think the first time I installed it (I tried several times) it told me something about it needing an intel mac to run, which, of course, I have.

[Edit: The first warning after opening system preferences and trying to load the Vox pref pane is: "You can’t open Vox Preferences preferences because it *doesn’t* work on an Intel-based Mac." Curious. Vox is quite recent. Why would they distribute a prefs pane extension that only works on PPC macs?]

Anyone got any ideas as to what's wrong with this pref pane?

Running 10.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please try as me

Step 1: Menu bar Apple > Preferences > Users & Group > Choose your account > select tab "Login items". Then keep the windows where you can easy-to-see

Step 2: Enable "Show hide items" for your Finder (in this step please search Google)

Step 3: You are using Finder to browse into /Library/PreferencePanes/. Then right click item "VOX Preferences.prefPane" and choose "Show contens package". Browsing into Contents > MacOS, at here you will see "VOXHelper.app"

Step 4: Drag "VOXHelper.app" and drop into "Login items" at Step 1

[image]

Step 5: Reboot your Mac. If not work, retry with "VOX Preferences" file.